# jquery cookie not being added properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Jquery:

```
// handle loading content
$(".link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".nav_head li a").removeClass('active-link');
    $(this).addClass('active-link');
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(".head .blue").text(title);
    var query = "func=load_page&title=" + title;
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process/process.php",
                data: query,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#content").empty().append(data);
                    var content = {content: data};
                    console.log("Create cookie");
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(content));
                    $.cookie('content', JSON.stringify(content));
                    console.log("End Cookie");
                    console.log($.cookie());
                },
    });
});
```

Console:

```
Create cookie train.js:85
{"content":"<span style=\"text-decoration: underline; font-size: 10pt;\"><strong>Humble Beginnings: &nbsp;The Start of Life</strong></span>"} train.js:86
End Cookie train.js:88
Object {content: "", menu: "[{"name":"intro","visible":true},{"name":"whatdoes…le":true},{"name":"manage_queue","visible":true}]"}
content: ""
menu: "[{"name":"intro","visible":true},{"name":"whatdoes","visible":false},{"name":"system","visible":false},{"name":"manage","visible":false},{"name":"audit_management","visible":true},{"name":"manage_queue","visible":true}]"
__proto__: Object
 train.js:89
```

As you can see above it creates a empty content cookie, is this because of the html in the string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was due to cookie string size limitations. I have worked around my problem by saving the query and rerunning the query on refresh.